# Execute another Python instance from different instance

Tags: python, exec

I currently have a script being executed by a program that comes with its own Python interpreter included.
This version does not include libraries I require so I use an os.exec to execute a second script against a locally installed instance of 2.7.

However the second script, when executed manually, works perfectly and doesn't have PYTHONPATH defined. If I log the output of PYTHONPATH when the wrapper is executed and when the second script is loaded they both have PYTHONPATH initialized to the original interpreters, which happens to also be a 2.6 instance.
This obviously has led me to believe I have some environmental variables being passed that I didn't anticipate, furthermore on 2 other systems this setup works 100% as expected whilst on this one system this behavior is happening.
Is there a cleaner way I could create a wrapper to call the second script? If not how could I avoid this unnecessary passing of env variables.

Comment: Why do you package a Python interpreter that does not suit your needs?  If you have to rely on a preinstalled version of Python anyway, there seems no point in including a Python interpreter in your package.

Comment: I haven't created the original program so have no control over the version included. This is just a required work around to extend the functionality

Comment: Have you tried using `os.execle` to explicitly pass the environment variables you desire?

Comment: I will have a look at the docs for it. Ideally I would prefer that I could execute it entirely using the locally installed interpreter and let it use any variables that are or are not set.

Comment: @unutbu If you would care to post that as an answer I will accept. I used it and just passed {} through to clear all env variables and everything is now functioning perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many variants of the [`os.exec*`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl) command:

```
execl(file, *args)
execle(file, *args, env)
execlp(file, *args)
execlpe(file, *args, env)
execv(path, args)
execve(path, args, env)
execvp(file, args)
execvpe(file, args, env)
```

- `l` variants use `*args`, `v` variants use `args`.
- `p` variants use the PATH environment variable to find `file`
- `e` varients replace the environment. Non-`e` variants use the env of
  current process.

You could use one of the `e` variants, such as `os.execle`, to control the environment variables passed to the new process.

Comment: Thanks. I used;
os.execve(Pythonbinary, args, {}) where {} passes no env variables through to the new script

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), that allows one to create basically a sandbox where you can install all the required libraries.

Comment: Thanks. While the answer above has solved my problem I'll be sure to bookmark that and have a good look at it sometime, just quickly scanning it I can see some possible uses for it in the future.